# What is tangle graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

The text I was reading states:

An n-node graph is said to be tangled if there is an edge leaving every set of [n/3] or fewer vertices. As a special case, the graph consisting of a single node is considered tangled. (Recall that the notation [x] refers to the smallest integer greater than or equal to x.)

Can someone explain to me what this means? what is tangled graph?

Comment: What are you confused by in the definition?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Hi misha, thanks for your response. I'm just not getting the entire statement itself. I'm not able to understand their description or definition of tangled graph.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I still haven't understood. I would really appreciate if you can help me out:)

Comment: If all you ask is the same question, then the best anyone can do is give you the same answer! If you can ask more specific questions about the definition, *then* someone can help you.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I said I don't understand their definition of tangled graph. They defined it as "an n-node graph is said to be tangled if there is an edge leaving every set of [n/3] or fewer vertices. As a special case, the graph consisting of a single node is considered tangled." what does this mean? More specifically my question is what do they mean by "if there is an edge leaving every set of [n/3] or fewer vertices. Can you explain this to me?

Comment: $[n/3]$, which is more commonly written $\lfloor n/3 \rfloor$ these days, is $n/3$ rounded down to the nearest integer. An edge "leaves a set of vertices" if it goes from one of the vertices in the set to one of the vertices not in the set.

Comment: Can you give me an example of such a graph? if it does not go to one of the vertices in the set then where does it go? I can't visualise this.

Comment: It has already been stated in the linked question that literally every connected graph is an example! (and there are others). For example, take the graph `a -- b -- c -- d -- e -- f`. If we take $S = \{a,b\}$, then there is an edge $bc$ leaving $S$ going to a vertex outside $S$. If we take $S = \{d,f\}$ then we can take of the edges $cd$, $de$, $ef$. And so on...

Comment: ohh now I'm getting there!. I was thinking of something completely different.. So like in the example you have 6 vertices so 6/3=2 and it is tangled because I can find a set of two vertices within 6 vertices whereby an edge leaves a set. Am I right? Also if I had 5 vertices then 5/3 = some decimal number(I guess 1.6666...). In this case what does S have to be? A set of 3 vertices? Meaning if then an edge leaves any set of 3 vertices in a graph and joins some other vertix then it would be tangled?

Comment: The definition says "every set". You have to check it for "every set". It says "$\lfloor n/3\rfloor$ or fewer", so we check it for smaller sets too; in the case of $n=5$ we would check it for the $1$-vertex sets.

Comment: @MishaLavrov okay so in the case of n =5 the set of vertices I can check it for will be 1 vertix set. it can't be 2 or 3 vertex sets because that is more than 5/3. The number of vertices in the set could be equal to n/3 or fewer but not more than n/3. And if an edge leaves "every" vertex set that has vertices less or equal to n/3 then it is tangled. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks a lot brother:) You have helped me in one of my previous question on graph theory when I couldn't find anything on the internet. I'm a self learner learning these subjects out of curiosity and sometimes I have no one to help me out. So I really appreciate you helping me out. Thanks again:)